# Создать DBF-файл из таблицы postgre

Tags: c#, .netcore2.0

Всем привет!
Нужна ваша помощь.
Проект над которым я работаю на .NET Core 2.0.
Мне нужно сформировать DBF-файл из получаемого списка (List<>).
В инете много примеров с использованием OleDb но на сколько я понял OleDb недоступен в .NET Core.
Какой библиотекой лучше воспользоваться для формирования DBF-файла и если возможно, пример с описанием???
Не могу разобраться!
Спасибо!

Comment: https://github.com/henck/dBASE.NET ?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо! Описание то, что надо.